# Mathematica 12.1 breaks exporting to postscript - workaround?

Tags: graphics, export, image

If you uncomment the `ColorFunction` in the code below, the resulting PS file is 200kb (compared to 32kb in 12.0) and is rejected by applications such as Scientific Workplace. Is there a workaround to this issue, other than switching back 12.0 which had its own slew of bugs?

```
g = Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}, 
   PlotRange -> 1.05 {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}];
g = Show[g,
   Graphics[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[8],Table[Circle[{0, 0}, r], {r, .5, 5, .5}]}],
   Table[ParametricPlot[5.2 {r Cos[a], r Sin[a]}, {r, 0, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[8]}(*, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, r}, GrayLevel[r]]*)], {a, 0, 6}]];
Export["Test.eps", g];
```

Comment: You could try exporting as PDF and then converting PDF to PS using, for example, Poppler.

Comment: I'm on SWP 5.0, which does not support PDF.

Comment: I get a 15 kB file in both 12.0 and 12.1. Looking into the files, I see no significant differences. I am on macOS.